# Why am unable to clean just a single project in my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

I have a solution with about 16 projects in it. When I manually clean a single project Visual Studio goes ahead and cleans all of them.

I've selected the "clean" option by right-clicking the project node in the Solution Explorer.

I expected it would clean only that one project. I could also see the logic potentially in cleaning other projects which depend on this one. But that's not what it does - it appears to clean the entire solution.

Most projects do not depend on (ie, reference) the one I selected. I checked this both by manually looking at the References node of every other project, and also by looking in Solution Properties > Common Properties > Project Dependencies. Nothing at all references the project in question.

The projects are mostly C# with one in VB.Net. The one I'm cleaning is C#.

Ultimately this isn't a disaster but it does waste a lot of time. If there is some way to prevent or fix this I'd like to do so.

Comment: You note the possible dependencies of other projects, but are there 'deeper level' dependencies involved here? For example, if your project depends on "A" and "B" then they will be cleaned; but also, if "A" depends on "C" then "C" will also get the wash.

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't think so... I updated the question with some more info on this.  In ABC example, which one represents the project I am trying to clean?

Comment: Could be some kind of disc-cache issue? When you "rebuild" the project in question (rather than the solution), is the whole solution similarly built, or does this only happen with "clean?" (On the ABC issue - your project is none of them!)

Comment: I did "Rebuild" by clicking on that specific project - and it rebuilds everything! It says "Rebuild All started" in the output window. So that seems like the same root issue

Answer (score 1):

Think the other way round, if you does not want the other project to be cleaned, that means you wish to keep the previous build result.

Then you can uncheck "Build" in "Configuration Manager" of the project you don't want to build (=do not want to clean).